# How to make a button element act like a block element (dimension-wise)

Tags: html, css, button

I have a button element and a div element.

The BUTTON element takes up as much space as needed by it's content.

The DIV element takes up the whole width, since it's a block element. I tried setting `display:block` on the button, that didn't do anything. Neither did `width:auto`.

I want the BUTTON to behave like the DIV in the example that I gave (see link below). I don't only want it to look like the DIV - I know I can set a manual width, but I want it to behave like a block element, that is automatically take up the whole available space.

Is that possible? And how?

Comment: You want both elements to be 100% width of it's container...? Why are you assigning a height to it?

Comment: i dont understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: I want the BUTTON to be like the DIV in the example that I gave (did you click on the link?). I don't only want it to look like the DIV - I know I can set a manual width, but I want it to behave like the DIV, that is take up the whole available space.
Oh, I actually did not specify that in the question. Will do now. Thanks.

Comment: @speak Typo - I meant width. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

you have to set the `min-width` for button element. check **[DEMO](http://liveweave.com/EEmOhE)**.

```
.container button,
.container div {
    display:block;
    min-width:100%; /*this makes the button extenable*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By Default Div Element occupy A row.
But Button is not like that So You have to Mention the Height and Width for it...

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
    <div class="container">
    <button>A button</button>
    <div>A div</div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
    * {
       border:0;
      }

    .container {
      outline:1px solid red;   
      padding: 0 3px 0 3px;
    }


    .container div {
      background-color:#33d;
    }

    .container button {
      background-color:#d33;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      width: 100%;
    }
```

Comment: That doesn't really work when there's a margin on the button element, though. It does not behave like a div with a margin. I'll be using margins.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you mean precisely by "I'll be using margins"?

Comment: The button and the DIV behave differently when a margin is set. The button overflows, but the DIV shrinks to accomodate the margin.
This is an old question but it seems that I was trying to have a button behave exactly like an un-styled DIV, for all sizing aspects (size, margin, padding), so that I can I can use the same CSS rules no a button and on a DIV. It must be impossible to achieve this in CSS.